# Start a GUI application at reboot

Tags: x11, startup

I'm trying to execute my own script (openMonitor.sh) via Cron on startup which opens a local html-file in Firefox and switches to fullscreen by emulating F11:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10;
export DISPLAY=:0.0 &&
export XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.xauthority &&
now=$(date +"%T")
echo "script run at "+$now >> /home/pi/monitor/run.log
/usr/bin/firefox --url /home/pi/monitor/monitor.html &
sleep 10;
xdotool key F11
```

The script is listed in crontab on my RaspberryPi2, Raspbian Jessie:

```
@reboot /home/pi/monitor/./openMonitor.sh
```

It's triggered successfully, the html-file is opened but Firefox doesn't switch to fullscreen. It's only working if I execute the script as a logged-in user.

As the crontab has 'minimal' environment and doesn't have the DISPLAY or XAUTHORITY environment set (and therefore no access to the X server), running xdotool on the connected display might be the issue here.
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't just that the `DISPLAY` environment isn't set, it's that the display might not even exist yet, and even if it does (there's a race condition between your cron job and the startup of the GUI), you don't have the right to use it. You need to log in on the GUI first.

`@reboot` entries in the crontab are for things to do independently of a login sessions. Displaying something on the console requires a login session.

Instead, enable autologin for the `pi` user. You can do that from `raspi-config` (see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47823/how-to-prevent-autologin-of-gui). Then add your script (startup of Firefox and window maximization) to the user's *login* script. If you're using the LXDE interface, you can add an entry in the autostart list: see [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up/45089#45089) (beware that many of the answers on this page don't work for a GUI program).